# global dictionary within a class python

Tags: python, class, global

I'm designing an inventory class in Python, it is supposed to keep track of the items a store has in stock, add new ones, and delete them, as well.

The trouble comes from my "item" definitions within the class.  When I add another item to my dictionary, it replaces it, it doesn't add it.  I appreciate your help! Why won't it add???

```
class Store:

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    # two accessor methods
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getEmail(self):
        return self.email

    # makes print work correctly
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    # items
    def additem(self, item, price):
        global items
        items = {}
        self.item = str(item)
        self.price = float(price)
        items[self.item] = price

    def delitem(self, item):
        items.remove(item)

    def displayinventory(self):
        return items
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are setting `items` to a new empty dictionary every time you call `additem`.  So it always erases whatever's there before adding a new item.  Instead, set `items = {}` once outside the function.  There is also no point in doing `self.item = str(item)` (and the same for the price), because this will just overwrite the existing `self.item`, so you'll only have access to the most recent one.

Actually, what you probably should do is make `items` an attribute of the object, like this:

```
class Store:

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.items = {}

    # rest of your code here. . .

    def additem(self, item, price):
        self.items[str(item)] = float(price)

    def delitem(self, item):
        del self.items[str(item)]

    def displayinventory(self):
        return self.items
```

The way you're doing it, there's only one global `items` dict that will be shared among all Stores.  The above way gives each store its own items dict so it can keep its own record of its own items.

Comment: Wow. Genius.  Thanks BrenBarn.  I'm new to Python, trying to learn.  Completely awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Even this was asked a view years ago, others might be interested in this answer.
If you want to use a dictionary globally within a class, then you need to define it in section where you use your class. 
if you are using your class in main, then define it there.
A dictionary or o list are global by default.

```
class Store:

    ...

    def additem (self, item, price):
        self.item = str (item)
        self.price = float (price)
        items [self.item] = price

def main ():
    ...
    items = dict ()
    myStore = Store ()
    ....
```